# resize UIImage according to the width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a NSMutableArray that contain several UIImage objects, these objects contain different dimensions and they all need to have the width of 140, but that will make the images really awful in my UICollectionView.

Is there a method where i put in the UIImage and then set the width 140 and then get the new height, which i need for the cell height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working code:**

```
    //create image array
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename.png"];
    NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image, nil];


    //get image original height, original width...
    CGFloat originalHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat originalWidth = image.size.width;

    //set wanted width and calculate wanted height...
    CGFloat wantedWidth = 140;
    CGFloat wantedHeight = (originalHeight*wantedWidth)/originalWidth;

    //call resize image method... setting wanted height and width....
    UIImage *avatarImage = [self imageWithImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(wantedWidth, wantedHeight)];
    //create imageView.. ... .
    UIImageView *avatarImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, wantedWidth, wantedHeight)];
    [avatarImageView setImage:avatarImage];
    [self.view addSubview:avatarImageView];
```

**Resize image method.**

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```